# How does Google+ determine which posts to display?

Tags: google-plus

Google+ has this nifty slider to choose how many posts go into the main stream.

[image]

**How does Google+ determine *which* posts should be displayed?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Google will let us know :) I'd guess they look for more popular ones or ones about topics you seem to care about.

Google is only starting/experimenting with the selection of interesting posts for their users. Facebook is far ahead with that. But I think Google is working on that every day and that they roll out slight advancements quite often. We will probably never know how they do it, as Facebook doesn't release that information either. Competition would benefit too much from this information. Google f.e. acquired some (I remember at least one) startups that focus specifically on finding user's interests and linking posts to that interests.